# TextView disable colourisation of symbols

Tags: android, textview

I am not sure what the distinction between the recent "emoji" and symbols like '♥' and '★' is, but as far as I know, symbols '♥' or '★' existed decades ago in the Korean character set (in fact, I typed '♥' using the symbol input of Microsoft Korean IME). On Windows these symbols have been treated like normal text, and have the same colour as the text.

In recent versions of Android, TextView started colourising symbols. For example, '♥' is displayed in orange red, even though I set the text colour to blue. On a Samsung device, '♥' does not even look like a character but a dark glowing 3D heart.

Can I make TextView display such symbols just characters like Windows does? I mean, I want them to have the same colour as the text, and to look like a character not an image.

Windows
[image: Windows]

Android
[image: Android]

Comment: Afaik you can't set the color of those symbols. Maybe you could try to draw the text onto a Canvas/Drawable and then display that in the wanted color, as a workaround.